# Force downloading an image via php script works but the image only opens in paint not photoshop

Tags: php

Here is my php script which executes the download:

```
$link = 'www.example.com';
$url = urlencode($link);

$image = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=75x75&cht=qr&chl=$url&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0";
$filename = file_get_contents("$image");


header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='qr code';");

header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));

echo $filename;
```

This downloads a file but it only opens in paint not photoshop. As a hint there doesn't appear to be a file type associated with the file (e.g. png or jpg).

I need all the headers above so this works in all browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a coding problem, your computer is set to use paint as its default image editor (or at least for the file type your sending)

Comment: This isn't a default image editor problem, please read the question carefully.

Comment: Answer has been found - simply need to remove single quotes from around filename.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps pass a file extension in your filename header.

> header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='qr_code.jpg';");

Comment: Sorry, still the same problem.